# How to change enable to disable in Td?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a question. I Have a table data

as like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enabled</td>
        <td><button class="js-enabled">Desabled</button></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Desabled</td>
         <td><button class="js-enabled">Enabled</button></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Enabled</td>
        <td><button class="js-enabled">Desabled</button></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Desabled</td>
         <td><button class="js-enabled">Enabled</button></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Enabled</td>
        <td><button class="js-enabled">Desabled</button></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Desabled</td>
         <td><button class="js-enabled">Enabled</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I used to this jquery function

```
$('.js-enabled').click(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith('<button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>');     
            });
```

**Now i want to**

1. if i click **enable Button** than change **Enabled To Disabled** `Left` and `Right` Both side

**[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/EGDZE/1/)**

Comment: whats the problem now dude ?

Comment: problum is this if i click right side button enabled than change text right side enable and left side disable ...

Comment: What do you mean by  - _Left and Right Both side_ ?

Comment: Yes i want to left or right side ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of the answer I'll use your code, but just to let you know, it's spelled 'Disabled'.

```
$('.js-enabled').click(function(){
    var button = $(this);
    var label = $(this).parent().prev('td');

    button.text() == 'Desabled' ? button.text('Enabled') : button.text('Desabled');
    label.text() == 'Desabled' ? label.text('Enabled') : label.text('Desabled');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EGDZE/2/

Comment: Wow it's nice i want to this  . This is browser compatible

Comment: HI @Kaloyan lvanov can i added class in my button if my button disabled than add class disbaled and if my button enabled than i added class enabled as like this my demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/EGDZE/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.js-enabled').click(function(){
    if($(this).text()=='Enabled')
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text('Disabled');
        $(this).text('Disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text('Enabled');
         $(this).text('Enabled');
    }
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/EGDZE/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-enabled').click(function(){
    var lableText = $(this).parent().parent().children().first();  
    (lableText.html() == "Desabled" ? lableText.html("Enable") : lableText.html("Desabled")); 
    $(this).html() == "Desabled" ? $(this).html("Enable") : $(this).html("Desabled");
});
```

Use this code.